# touch Function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I recently added a touch function in PowerShell profile file

```
PS> notepad $profile
```

```bsh
function touch {Set-Content -Path ($args[0]) -Value ($null)}
```

Saved it and ran a test for

```
touch myfile.txt
```

error returned:

```
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ touch myfile
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you close and reopen the powershell console?

Comment: Yes I did it multiple times, still did not work.

Comment: That is *not* a proper implementation of `touch`, unless you like the idea of accidentally destroying files. If this "function" of `touch` is all you need, consider renaming it `Empty-File` or similar... Or consider a more careful implementation, like `Add-Content $File $null ; (dir $File).LastWriteTime = Get-Date`.

Comment: Have you double checked the path of the profile file and that it actually gets loaded? Type `explorer $profile` in the console to verify the path and maybe add `write-host loaded` to the profile to verify it gets loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PowerShell there are naming conventions for functions. It is higly recommended to stick with that if only to stop getting warnings about it if you put those functions in a module and import that.

A good read about naming converntion can be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/01/naming-and-designing-advanced-powershell-functions/).

Having said that, Powershell DOES offer you the feature of *Aliasing* and that is what you can see here in the function below.

As Jeroen Mostert and the others have already explained, a Touch function is NOT about destroying the content, but only to set the LastWriteTine property to the current date.
This function alows you to specify a date yourself in parameter `NewDate`, but if you leave it out it will default to the current date and time.

```
function Set-FileDate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [datetime]$NewDate = (Get-Date),
        [switch]$Force
    )
    Get-Item $Path -Force:$Force | ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime = $NewDate }
}
Set-Alias Touch Set-FileDate -Description "Updates the LastWriteTime for the file(s)"
```

Now, the function has a name PowerShell won't object to, but by using the `Set-Alias` you can reference it in your code by calling it `touch`

Comment: Just to mention it, a common use of touch is to create a file of zero length if it doen't already exist. Otherwise +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that creates a new file if it does not exist or updates the timestamp if it does exist.

```
Function Touch-File
{
    $file = $args[0]
    if($file -eq $null) {
        throw "No filename supplied"
    }

    if(Test-Path $file)
    {
        (Get-ChildItem $file).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
    }
    else
    {
        echo $null > $file
    }
}
```

If you  have a set of your own custom functions stored in a .ps1 file, you must first import them before you can use them, e.g.

```
Import-module .\MyFunctions.ps1 -Force
```

Comment: Bad idea. If the file is created after `Test-Path` tests (which could happen in another session), it will still be merrily destroyed. Aside from that, `echo $null > $file` will not create an empty (0 byte) file; it will be a 2 byte file containing a BOM. Instead of testing, `Add-Content $file $null` will create the file if it does not exist, or leave it alone if it does.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Add-Content is better.  Why not make an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion:

- **If you have placed your function definition in your `$PROFILE` file, it will be available in *future* PowerShell sessions** - unless you run `. $PROFILE` in the current session to reload the updated profile.

  - Also note that loading of `$PROFILE` (all profiles) can be *suppressed* by starting a session with `powershell.exe -NoProfile` (Windows PowerShell) / `pwsh -NoProfile` (PowerShell (Core)).
- As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) points out in a comment on the question, **naming your function `touch` is problematic, because your function *unconditionally* truncates an *existing* target file** (discards its content), whereas the standard [`touch`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) utility on Unix-like platforms leaves the *content* of existing files alone and only updates their last-write (and last-access) timestamps.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67665941/45375) for **more information about the `touch` utility** and **how to implement equivalent behavior in PowerShell**.