# touch command not working, what should I use instead?

Tags: powershell, file, visual-studio-code, command-line, terminal

I am trying to create an empty file using terminal in vs-code but the command line isn't in the mood to work. I don't understand whats wrong?

This is the error when I try to make the file:

```
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ touch app.js
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Where are you getting the term `touch` from? What are you trying to do

Comment: If you mean to have a function you can call wityh `touch` in PowerShell, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51842880/9898643) is what you're looking for?

Comment: i am trying to create an empty file

Comment: Then have a look at the [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) cmdlet.

Comment: You can also do `$null > app.js`. Easy way of creating files.

Comment: @NeelKotkar - `touch.exe` is NOT a native windows command , nor  is it a built in windows utility. the only ways to get such is to [A] install that util [the git-for-windows install does that] _OR_ [B] create a similar util as a function.

Comment: duplicates: [Creating new file through Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45446285/995714), [Equivalent of Linux `touch` to create an empty file with PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/q/502374/241386), [Touch command not working in Terminal of VSC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56417937/995714). Also related: [Create an empty file on the commandline in windows (like the linux touch command)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011267/995714), [How to create an empty file at the command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1702762/995714)

Answer (score 3):

As [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out, **`touch` is neither a PowerShell command nor a standard utility (external program) *on Windows***; by contrast, on Unix-like platforms [`touch` is a standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) with dual purpose:

- (a) When given *existing* file paths, the files' last-modified (`.LastWriteTime`) and last-accessed (`.LastAccessTime`) timestamps are set to the current point in time, by default.
- (b) When given *non-existing* file paths, such files are *created*, by default.

There is *no* equivalent command in PowerShell (as of PowerShell 7.2), but you can use existing commands to implement (a) and (b) separately, and you can write a custom script or function that provides both (a) and (b) in a manner similar to the Unix `touch` utility:

- PowerShell implementation of (a), via [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) and the properties of a [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance:

```sh
# Update the last-modified and last-accessed timestamps of existing file app.js
$file = Get-Item -LiteralPath app.js
$file.LastWriteTime = $file.LastAccessTime = Get-Date
```

- PowerShell implementation of (b), using the [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) cmdlet:

```sh
# Create file app.js in the current dir.
# * If such a file already exists, an error will occur.
# * If you specify -Force, no error will occur, but the existing file will be 
# *truncated* (reset to an empty file).
$file = New-Item app.js
```

Note: When a file is created, it is a `0`-byte file by default, but you may pass content via the `-Value` parameter.

---

[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) suggests the following technique to implement the *conditional* nature
of the `touch` utility's file creation:

```sh
# * If app.js exists, leaves it untouched (timestamps are *not* updated)
# * Otherwise, create it.
Add-Content app.js $null
```

Note:

- To get `touch`-like behavior, (a) (updating the last-write and last-accessed timestamps) must still be implemented separately.
- At least hypothetically the [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) approach can *fail*, namely if an existing target file is *read-only* - whereas manipulating such a file's *timestamps* may still work. (While you could suppress the error, doing so could make you miss true failures.)

The next section points to a custom function that wraps both (a) and (b), while also providing additional functionality that the Unix `touch` utility offers.

---

A **custom function named `Touch-File`** that implements *most* of the functionality of the Unix `touch` utility - which has several options to provide additional behaviors beyond the defaults described above - is **available from [this MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/82ed8e73bb1d17c5ff7b57d958db2872)**.
Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can directly download and define it the current session as follows, which also provides guidance on how to make it available in future sessions:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/82ed8e73bb1d17c5ff7b57d958db2872/raw/Touch-File.ps1 | iex
```

Note: `Touch` is not an [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) in PowerShell, but it was chosen nonetheless,
because none of the approved verbs can adequately convey the core functionality of
this command.

Sample call:

```sh
# * If app.js exists, update its last-write timestamp to now.
# * Otherwise, create it (as an empty file).
Touch-File app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
Out-File -FilePath "app.js"
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Does this definitely work in lieu of `touch`, in the exact same way?

Comment: Actually not. linux touch command creates the file if not existing or updates timestamp if existing. It may desverve to write a kind of touch-file function to mimic this as out-file as used here only create an empty file.

Comment: In _Windows PowerShell_ (up to v5.1, the Windows-only legacy edition that comes with Windows) the resulting file won't be _empty_: Because `Out-File file` there defaults to "Unicode" encoding (UTF-16LE), the file is created with a UTF-16LE _BOM_ (byte-order-mark), i.e. with the following _2 bytes_: `0xFF 0xFE`. Ditto with `$null > file`, which in effect is an alias for `Out-File`. Use `Set-Content file $null` or `New-Item file` for truly empty files. By contrast, the cross-platform _PowerShell (Core)_ edition (v6+) consistently uses BOM-less UTF-8, so `Out-File` / `$null >` work there too.