# visual studio code touch command not recognized

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is not recognizing the touch index.html command .  It used to work.  Now I get this error:

PS C:\Users\kimim_000\mynewprofile> touch index.html
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- touch index.html
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well. I used "code" in place of "touch" to create my file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PowerShell?

I think this answer explains it well if you are.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67665941/15102120

Basically, `touch` isn't a PowerShell or Windows command. The command if this is the issue is `New-Item` or `Get-Item`